# Xcode 4.3 crashing after Run

Tags: crash, osx-lion, xcode4.3

Good day!
I have strange problem with Xcode 4.3.
When I'm trying to run any app - it crashing with the following exception:

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E109
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in       'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB' while firing fault for extension    'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB'
UserInfo: {
NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in     failed.\" UserInfo=0x4017c8300 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB,     DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugi  n/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path   \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d could not be   loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged.,    NSUnderlyingError=0x400fb5c00 \"The bundle \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded   because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
```

Reinstallation and downgrade to 4.2.1 did not help :(

Could somebody help? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this problem once before and a reinstall of Xcode fixed the problem. Are you downloading Xcode from the Mac App Store or developer.apple.com? Try reinstalling from the one you are not using.

Comment: @rapt0r did you do a full reinstall or just an update? Make sure you completely delete Xcode from your hard drive and reinstall.

Comment: Strange, but did not help (( I completely removed (using CleanMyMac), than downloaded 4.3.1 from developer.apple.com and got the same exception...

Answer (score 1):

Is Xcode trying to open a specific project? if so, move it out of the way (rename, move somewhere else). After it, open xcode as usually, did it crash? if no maybe your project is the one with the problem...

Answer (score 0):

uninstall Xcode, reboot, and reinstall from an other source ([Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12&affId=403761) or [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://nslog.me/2011/03/xcode-4-problems/)  could help you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be obsoleted keychain certificates. I heard one of my friend solved nasty crash issue by this.

You can display them by "Display" => "Show expired certificates" (Not exact -- I'm using Japanese translated version at this moment) in the Key Chain Access application.

Then, you can sort by expirely date. Then, all of the certificates before today (also marked with red X icon) possibly removed. Careful *NOT* remove non-expired certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this crash today. I searched for it and tried "Do Not Use Auto layout" "Update the Xcode" "Reinstall Xcode".They all didn't work. I still don't know how this crash happened. But maybe you are able to try this way: Product-Scheme-Edit Scheme-Debugger-Change "LLDB" into "none". Then it works.